# Node giving error "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638" - Telegraf - Telegram bot api - Windows

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I recently downloaded and installed **Telegraf - telegram bot api**. It works with **Node.js**. I looked at 17 sites, including github, and did not find a solution for myself.

Here is the error:

```
node .\src\bot.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Projects\Telegram\src\bot.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

And my code for **bot.js**:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome!'))
bot.launch()
```

**My system:** Windows 10 64bit

**IDE:** Visual Studio Code 1.38.1

**Node version:** 10.16.3

**Npm version:** 6.11.3

Please do not give me links to the solution found from Google. I tried it over 100 times. If you understand, help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself! It turns out the case in the file name. Since the folder is called "bot" and the file inside is also "bot.js". This gives a name conflict.

**Solution**

> Rename file **bot.js** to **tg-bot.js**

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro I solved the problem first run the code on cmd using node bot.js command where bot.js is the file name and current directory is directory containing bot.js

If the error occurs just give npm install telegraf and the problem is solved

This is true for any module not found errors replace telegraf with the module that is missing in your case.

Good day!